# how to install last.fm scrobbler on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

http://www.last.fm/download?showplatform=Linux

it has the guide for 12.10 but not newer ones
plz someone help

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install lastfm-scrobbler` what's happen after that ?

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter which repository do you use. Each repository installs the same version.

Eg the debian repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.last.fm/debian stable main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lastfm-scrobbler
```

---

But there seems to be a error in the desktop file `/usr/share/applications/lastfm-client.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Last.fm Client
Comment=Listen to Last.fm radio
Exec=/usr/bin/lastfm-client
Icon=lastfm-client
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Qt;Audio;AudioVideo;
StartupNotify=true
```

The binary `Exec=/usr/bin/lastfm-client` doesn't exist. Therefore open the file in an editor

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/lastfm-client.desktop
```

and change the line `Exec=` from

```
Exec=/usr/bin/lastfm-client
```

to

```
Exec=/usr/bin/lastfm-scrobbler
```

---

Alternatively you could copy the file into your local applications folder

```
cp /usr/share/applications/lastfm-client.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/lastfm-client.desktop
sudo chown $USER:USER ~/.local/share/applications/lastfm-client.desktop
```

and make the changes in this file via

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/lastfm-client.desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that apt.last.fm is no longer active, so the above answer will not work anymore.

Installation of lastfm (not lastfm-scrobbler) from the source indicated [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/779975/549880) could still work (in Xubuntu 18.04 in my case), but it seems lastfm still has trouble talking to the network components, and can't login to my account.

Anyway, if you want simpler installations of these older .debs without running a separate command to fix dependencies every time, you can use gdebi instead of dpkg, so the method from the linked answer would go more like this:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
wget security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lastfm/lastfm_1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi lastfm_1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

But I gave up when I saw the network problem, I don't know how or if that can be fixed in 18.04.