# How to install last.fm scrobbler on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, last.fm-client

since last.fm for spotify doesn't seem to work anymore I tried to install the scrobbler on my Ubuntu without success. I don't know if I'm 
adding the right repository or missing something.

I tried some tutorials I found on the net but without success and when I manage to install the scrobbler, it always installs the older version and I want the new one.

Can someone explain me, step by step, how do I install it?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/662228/how-to-install-last-fm-scrobbler-on-ubuntu-14-04