# How do I install Lastfm scrobbler(newbie at Ubuntu stuff)?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, last.fm-client

I am new to Ubuntu,how can I install last.fm scrobbler?

I have already downloaded via the website(http://www.last.fm/download) but I don't know what to do now. Any help, especially newbie-friendly,would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you try visiting [this link](http://apt.last.fm/)? It should open up your "Software Updates" app and ask if you want to add the repository...

Comment: @TheBrownOne That link does not work for me, just loads for ever, did you test it?

Comment: take a look at a file named `README.md`, it contains some instructions, try to follow them.

Comment: @TheBrownOne Still loading...

Comment: @Bilal There are two files liblastfm-1.0.5 and lastfm-desktop-2.1.30, I read both README.md files.I first did what it told me to at liblastfm but i stucked when it said 
mkdir _build && cd _build
    cmake ..
    sudo make install
why use ".."??

Comment: @MarkKirby I tried this thread,but i could not understand what to do :/

Comment: Ok I will install it on my PC, then do an answer for this version.

Comment: Sorry guys, not a dupe, the repo is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found it, just click [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lastfm/lastfm_1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) and it will download,then choose open in the software center

or in a terminal

```
wget security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lastfm/lastfm_1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i lastfm_1.5.4.27091+dfsg1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix dependencies.

It is a 14.04 .deb but it installed on my 16.04, no problem, I found it on [Ubuntu updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/lastfm)

Comment: I try to install it  but it cant be installed,when i press install it goes for a sec to "installing" and then it returns to install, the installation never takes place.There is a new icon at the side menu that indicates"waiting for the installation to complete"(translated from greek).

Comment: Try it the terminal way, what is you Ubuntu version?

Comment: I run the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: That is an old bug in 16.04, it should be fixed, open a terminal and run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to update your system and the software center should work.